# prevent duplicate entries by matching a subset of fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, constraints

I have an insert statement that inserts tags into a table. Each tag has a unique `id` (for referencing), a `vid_id` (for matching to a video), and a `name` (ex. tag1).

A duplicate entry would be considered having an existing entry with `vid_id` and `name` as the same as whatever is being inserted.

How do I stop the insert for a duplicate entry that matches 2/3 fields?

```
$sql="INSERT into tags (id,vid_id,name) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt16 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt16->execute(array($id,$vid_id,$tag));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to create a unique contraint composed by `vid_id` and `name` and you are all set!

This is how you do it:

```
alter table tags add unique (vid_id, name);
```

Once created, your unique constraint will forbid the insertion of values that would produce duplicate rows given your unique definition (the fields involved).

That's also true for updates (ah, have you though of that?): if you try to update a record and the update will produce a duplicate, the unique constraint will block it.

Comment: But won't that make it so neither values can exist if duplicate? I only want so that if both values match so `id:123,name:tag1` cannot occur twice. I don't care if `id:123,name:tag2` coexists with `id:123,name:tag1`.

Comment: But haven't you just said that "A duplicate entry would be considered having an existing entry with vid_id and name as the same as whatever is being inserted"??

Comment: The ways it's defined, the unique constraint will suit your needs. Maybe if you post a table with current values, we could all understand better this issue...

Comment: nvm it works perfectly. Sorry Adrian lol. I had duplicates already in my table when I executed it so it threw off my thinking.

Answer (score 1):

create a unique index on these 2 columns.